# Redirect after posts are completed on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

On my page I have an `onSubmit` attribute to handle my submit event. The function of the submit and the page element are listed below.
On submit I first want to post a ruleset, and when I get the response with the ID of the ruleset, I post all rules individually.
Now, after everything has been submitted, I want to redirect to another page, called `rulesets_modify`.

I've tried Passing a `useNavigate` from the `NewRuleset` page to the `handleSubmit` function, and calling this after all rule posts. I get navigated over correctly, but on the `rulesets_modify` page, it isn't able to get the data. I can retrieve the ruleset data, but the rule data is empty. This makes me believe that the navigation is happening before everything is done being submitted. After refreshing the `rulesets_modify` page, everything is loaded correctly.

How could I solve this?

**Page element rulesets_new:**

```
export default function NewRuleset() {
  // Add table columns
  // Add useStates
  // Function to add new rule
  // useEffects to get data from API

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
    <Header text='Regelset aanmaken' />
      <Form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event, RulesetName, EngineOid, ProcessOid, Rules, navigate)}>
        <RnRulesetsTopRow 
          // Params
        />
        
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <RnTable columns={columns} data={Rules} Rules={Rules} setRules={setRules} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Button type="submit" variant='success'>Save</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Button className='float-right' onClick={(e) => addNewRule(e, setRules)}>+</Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

**function handleSubmit:**

```
export function handleSubmit(e, RulesetName, EngineOid, ProcessOid, Rules, nav) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newRulesetJson = `{...}`;

  const RulesetPostOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: newRulesetJson
  };

  postRuleset(RulesetPostOptions)
    .then(response => {

      Rules.forEach(Rule => {
        let seq = (Rule.SequenceNumber) ? Rule.SequenceNumber : "";
        let name = (Rule.Name) ? Rule.Name : "";
        let desc = (Rule.Description) ? Rule.Description : "";
        let exp = (Rule.Expression) ? Rule.Expression : "";

        let RuleJson = `{...}`;
    
        let RulesPostOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: RuleJson
        };
    
        postRule(RulesPostOptions)
      });
      nav('/rulesets_modify?rulesetOid='+response.Oid);
    })
};
```

**function postRuleset:**

```
export const postRuleset = async (RulesetPostOptions) => {
  return fetch('api-url.com', RulesetPostOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `handleSubmit` isn't waiting for all the network requests to complete prior to navigating. The `Rules.forEach` is completely synchronous.

Assuming `postRule` is also an asynchronous function like `postRuleset` I'd suggest ***mapping*** the `Rules` array to an array of Promise objects and using `Promise.all` on them to wait for them all to be fulfilled, ***and then*** issuing the navigation action.

Example:

```
export async function handleSubmit(
  e,
  rulesetName,
  engineOid,
  processOid,
  rules,
  navigate
) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newRulesetJson = `{...}`;

  const rulesetPostOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: newRulesetJson
  };

  const response = await postRuleset(rulesetPostOptions);

  // Create array of postRule requests
  const ruleRequests = rules.map(Rule => {
    const seq = rule.SequenceNumber || "";
    const name = rule.Name || "";
    const desc = rule.Description || "";
    const exp = rule.Expression || "";

    const ruleJson = `{...}`;
    
    const rulesPostOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: RuleJson
    };
    
    return postRule(rulesPostOptions); // <-- return Promise!
  });

  // Wait for all postRule requests to resolve
  await Promise.all(ruleRequests);

  navigate('/rulesets_modify?rulesetOid=' + response.Oid);
};
```

Comment: How would I go about error handling in `PostRule` and returning that in an alert to the user, when some of the rules were to get an error on posting?

Comment: @R.Gore `handleSubmit` is an `async` function, I'd probably start by looking at surrounding the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` so if any of the Promises reject or there's any other thrown exceptions they can be caught & handled.